What could explain missing packets between two servers on the same subnet?
Server A:192.168.100.10 Server B:192.168.100.61  Server C:10.1.11.171
Server B makes a request to server C (via server A):
telnet 10.1.11.171 7777
A tcpdump -i ens4 port 7777 on server A shows the below output. In essence, we can see that server C responds to server B when inspecting traffic on the LAN interface on server A (which forwards the traffic). This interface is configured for the subnet 192.168.100.0/24.
16:15:44.567765 IP 192.168.100.61.60454 > 10.1.11.171.7777: Flags [S], seq 1044174687, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 625522895 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:15:44.610705 IP 10.1.11.171.7777 > 192.168.100.61.60454: Flags [S.], seq 3053725531, ack 1044174688, win 62643, options [mss 1375,sackOK,TS val 645556679 ecr 625522895,nop,wscale 7], length 0

However, the packets never arrive at 192.168.100.33.
Routing table on server A:
default via [PUBLICIP/REDACTED] dev ens3 proto dhcp src [PUBLICIP/REDACTED] metric 100 
10.1.0.0/16 dev aws-ovh-1 scope link metric 100 
[PUBLICIP/REDACTED] dev ens3 proto dhcp scope link src [PUBLICIP/REDACTED] metric 100 
169.254.68.176/30 dev aws-ovh-1 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.68.178 
192.168.100.0/24 dev ens4 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.10 metric 100 
[PUBLICIP/REDACTED] via [PUBLICIP/REDACTED] dev ens3 proto dhcp src [PUBLICIP/REDACTED] metric 100

The only iptables entry on server A :
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
SNAT       all  --  10.1.0.0/16          0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW to:192.168.100.10

The idea is that new connections from 10.1.0.16 should be SNAT'ed, while responses from 10.1.0.0/16 should not. Although a separate thread, I assumed that a route to 10.1.0.0/16 via 192.168.100.10 would eliminate the need for this rule. However, to get traffic to work from 10.1.0.0/16 to 192.168.100.0/24, this rule needs to be in place.

IP forwarding is enabled on server A.
There are no iptables rules on server C.

I've been debugging this for days now, but I'm at loss
What could explain the missing packets?
Updates in response to comments
A tcpdump -e -i ens4 port 7777 on server A shows :

17:15:26.829429 fa:16:3e:fa:31:bf (oui Unknown) > fa:16:3e:a7:bf:fa (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 10.1.11.171.7777 > 192.168.100.61.48840: Flags [S.], seq 3209050840, ack 3739727334, win 62643, options [mss 1375,sackOK,TS val 649138880 ecr 629105113,nop,wscale 7], length 0

This matches the IP address of the interface of server B which is connected to 192.168.100.0/24 :
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:a7:bf:fa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s3
    inet 192.168.100.61/24 metric 100 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global dynamic ens3
       valid_lft 57996sec preferred_lft 57996sec


Can you verify with tcpdump -e that the packets are being sent to the correct MAC address?

As an unrelated note, "ctstate NEW" in nat table rules is most likely redundant – the entire table is only processed for new packets anyway. Responses that match a conntrack state won't go through the rules at all.

@u1686_grawity updated the question based on your question.

When I see this sort of nonsense happening, one thing I always try first is a cold power-cycle - shut the machines down, kill wall power for 20 seconds (or until network carrier lights go out - net cards are powered on 5Vsb and that can take as much as a minute to drain down) and restart. While this is uncommon in server-grade hardware, I've seen it a lot in consumer grade stuff; it seems net cards, which are always powered as long as there is wall power to support WoL, can fragment their internal memory and start losing packets of specific types or from specific hosts due to that; and because they stay powered through even a normal power cycle, that fragmentation is never resolved.

Thanks! This is a cloud server at OVH, and the networking is based on openstack (so all virtual). I’ve tried rebooting the servers, but the issue remains :-(
